# How can i add report data source using report viewer vs 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

When I click "choose data source"

then it popup and having "choose instance for data sources used in the report"
and it has 2 rows

```
report data source | data source instance
-----------------------------------------
dataset1           |configblindingsource 
dataset2           |userblidingsource
-----------------------------------------
```

pic: http://www.thaicreate.com/upload/stock/20130302152411.jpg

I want to add the dataset3

how can I add the dataset3 to my report data source ?

I'm using 1 report and 2 tables now I want to use 1 report 3 table

but I can't find the way to add the dataset3 to my report

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251724.aspx

Comment: this isn't that i want, i want to have 3 table in 1 report not using "join" but thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a dataset, while viewing the rdlc file, open the 'Report Data' window (if you don't already have it open it's View->Report Data).  In the top left corner of that window, click on New->DataSet.